# rqt install in Fuerte / git target directories

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, git, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros experts!

I want to install the rqt Package to my **fuerte** ROS version in ubuntu precise.
I am following the instructions on
see wiki.ros.org/rqt/UserGuide/Install/Groovy
(At the end of the page)
Then I have problems with the sentence:
"Clone the git repositories qt_gui_core and rqt"
As far as I know to clone a git repository you need to specify the target directory.

The question:
**what is the target directory where to clone the git rqt and qt_gui_core repository?**

I am really new in ROS so I hope the question makes sense if not just tell me what I am not understanding.

THANK YOU!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98466/rqt-install-in-fuerte-/-git-target-directories/) by [LovedByJesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8516/lovedbyjesus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LovedByJesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8516/lovedbyjesus/) on 2013-11-07**:
My question is quite similar to the one on this link
http://answers.ros.org/question/66255/install-rqt-on-fuerte-from-source-help/

I think we both stumbled upon the same problem:
'The instructions to install rqt on Fuerte are not detailed enough for beginners'. Please fix it or answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the one hand it is sad that I have to answer my own question ( could no body help me for such long time? :_( ) on the other hand it is nice to see that I have learnt something in ROS! ;-)

The direct answer to the question is:
**clone the repository on your personal ROS workspace**

You should have one already created (this personal workspace is also called **overlay**). If you followed the ROS [installation instructions of configuring a new environment](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment), *Create a ROS workspace*, you should have already one personal workspace where to install the packages.

In my case it is `/work/<user>/ros_fuerte_workspace`.

And what you should actually do in your workspace is just **install rqt as a new package**. (There is a general answer about installing a package [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/10581/installing-ros-packages-from-source/) ) I will give you the particular installation method using a rosinstall file. Therefore I will provide you as well with the *rosinstall* file `rqt.rosinstall` that you must execute **in your personal workspace** with the following command

(there is an important *dot* in the middle of the expression!)

```
rosinstall . rqt.rosinstall
```

That is the code that I you should write in the file *rqt.rosinstall*

```
#installing rqt
#Two stacks needed 'qt_gui_core' and 'rqt'
#see http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/UserGuide/Install/Groovy last Headline "Installing on Fuerte"

- git: {local-name: qt_gui_core, uri:  'https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core.git', version: fuerte-devel}

- git: {local-name: rqt, uri: 'https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt.git', version: fuerte-devel}
```

The # lines are comments, you may leave them out (but I would keep them comments are good ;-))

On executing *rosinstall* on this file the subfolders `rqt`  and `qt_gui_core` are created. Now you just gotta build them! (Go inside each of them and run rosmake)

```
rosmake
```

**READY!!** now you can use *rqt* on fuerte by writing:

```
rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui
```

Hallelujah! :-)

---

Originally posted by [LovedByJesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8516/lovedbyjesus/) with karma: 86 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
I'm glad you were able to learn yourself and solve your problem. This is a very important skill. Sorry that nobody was able to give you hints. It probably slipped the radar.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-03**:
And thank you for coming back to provide the answer yourself.

**Comment by [LovedByJesus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8516/lovedbyjesus/) on 2014-04-03**:
Hey thanks for your encouragement. After so long waiting for the answer I could not keep it for myself!
And at the end I even got a 'self-learner badge' ;-)